What is the correct way to use a Recafimil reusable capsule for the Nespresso Vertuoline?
I enjoy the convenience and ease of cleaning a Nespresso compared to a more manual espresso machine. However, I miss being able to brew my favorite grounds. I recently purchased a Racafimil stainless steel reusable pod. I've tried using it a few times following the directions on the box, but it has come out watery and weak both times.
Does anyone have experience using this or a similar reusable pod for the Verturo line? Can I get a richer flavor in my double espresso using one of these pods?
